# Смена цвета текста в навигационной панели

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Недавно начал изучать xcode и obj c, поэтому вопросы соответственные) Как поменять цвет текста навбара?

Comment: Я так и сделал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]};
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```